# Using Java remove unbalanced/unpartnered parenthesis

Tags: java, regex, string, string-parsing

I want to remove all the "unpartnered" or unpaired parenthesises from a string.

```
exampleStr = back-pay) zyzhk1219(17) zyzhk1329 zyzhk1595(15) zyzhk1988 zyzhk2004 zyzhk2131) jswioj((testsjkldf
```

The expected "parenthesis balanced" string should be

```
back-pay zyzhk1219(17) zyzhk1329 zyzhk1595(15) zyzhk1988 zyzhk2004 zyzhk2131 jswiojtestsjkldf
```

I saw some ruby based solution on stackoverflow. But, couldn't find one I can use in java.

Comment: Can you confirm the output you expect based on your example?

Comment: And your question is ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How it might be done in pseudo-code:

```
initialize parenLevel = 0
for each character in string
    if char is ( increment parenLevel
    if char is )
        if parenLevel = 0, remove bad paren
        else, decrement parenLevel
next

initialize parenLevel = 0
for each character in string in reverse
    if char is ) increment parenLevel
    if char is (
        if parenLevel = 0, remove bad paren
        else, decrement parenLevel
next
```

How it might be implemented in practice: http://ideone.com/K3s0X

Sample result:

```
back-pay zyzhk1219(17) zyzhk1329 zyzhk1595(15) zyzhk1988 zyzhk2004 zyzhk2131 jswiojtestsjkldf
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pseudo code and the java code. Before asking the question, I was trying  something similar to your pseudo code, but, I kept running in infinite loop for some outlying conditions like multiple nested parenthesis. Your java code was super helpful in pointing my error.

Comment: Thought this might interest you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929168/how-to-remove-unbalanced-unpartnered-double-quotes-in-java

Answer (score 1):

This works correctly on your example string:

```
s = s.replaceAll("([^()]*(?:\\([^()]*\\)[^()]*)*)[()]", "$1");
```

Or, in more readable form:

```
(
  [^()]*          # some non-parentheses
  (?:
    \([^()]*\)    # a matched pair of parens
    [^()]*        # some more non-parens
  )*
)
[()]              # one unpaired paren
```

I'm assuming you don't want to allow nested pairs of parentheses.  For example, in this string:

```
"abc(def(ghi)jkl)mno"
```

...the first `(` and the last `)` should be removed, leaving this:

```
"abcdef(ghi)jklmno"
```

If you do want to allow nesting, there's no pure regex solution--at least, not in Java.